# Arduino serial.read to int

Tags: arduino, serial

I am trying to read a serial string which comes through as "R0123" for example then I need the 0123 to be in an int. to send out through another method

Here is my code it is not working the way that I think it should

```
void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    delay(100);
    if(Serial.read() == 'R')
      {
        int r1 = Serial.read();
        int r2 = Serial.read();
        int r3 = Serial.read();
        int r4 = Serial.read();
        int red = ((int)r1 * 1000) + ((int)r2 * 100) + ((int)r3 * 10) + (int)r4;

        sb.sendColour(red,0,0);

        Serial.print(r1,0);
        Serial.print(r2,0);
        Serial.print(r3,0);
        Serial.print(r4,0);
        Serial.print(red);
      }
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about using atoi()?
You will still need to trim of the 'R', and you might have to pad it with a NULL character at the end ('\0').
But then it should work as:

```
int rInteger = atoi(s);
```

when s is a pointer to a null terminated string.

Comment: So if i do Serial.read into a string for the four characters then add \o and run in it atoi it should work

Comment: I am getting an error ArduinoShiftyWireless.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
ArduinoShiftyWireless:45: error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int atoi(const char*)'

Comment: Like I said, atoi() doesn't take a string, it takes a pointer to a string, or to an array of chars, hence the error :)
I am not sure if arduino uses ANSI C(?)
Never the less, this should be accurate enough: http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.13.html#atoi

Comment: Frankly, I'm a little rusty on my C, bit something like
    
    //code to read the 'R' character
    char* readString;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        readString[i]=Serial.Read();
    }
    int a = atoi(readString);
    
I imagine would do the trick.

Comment: Ehh formatting?
See it here: http://pastebin.com/Q4GCLh75

Comment: Good to hear it :)

Answer (score 8):

You are confusing integer values and ascii character values. When your

```
  int r1 = Serial.read();
```

reads a 0 it will read the ASCII character 0. The integer value of the character 0 is (decimal) 48 (check for instance this [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)). So instead that line should read

```
  int r1 = Serial.read() - 48;
```

or even better

```
  int r1 = Serial.read() - '0';
```

Answer (score 5):

This reads 4 characters after the "R", places them in a `char` array and appends a `null` character. Then converts to integer. The code doesn't check if there are at least 4 chars following the "R", or that they are digits, though.

```
#define numberOfDigits 4
char theNumberString[numberOfDigits + 1];
int theNumber;

if(Serial.read() == 'R')
  {
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; theNumberString[i++] = Serial.Read());
  theNumberString[numberOfDigits] = 0x00;
  theNumber = atoi(theNumberString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
int intParse(byte length) //return parsed byte from serial
{    
  char BUFFER[length + 1];
  delay(5); //need for Baud 9600, less delay for faster speed
  for(byte i = 0; i < length; i++)    
    BUFFER[i] = Serial.read();   
  BUFFER[length] = 0; //I had this earlier, but not necessary for Arduino.
  return atoi(BUFFER);
}
```

For example: R1234
You would write:

```
void loop()
{
  char input = Serial.read();
  if(input == 'R')
  {
    int output = intParse(4);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should also set `BUFFER[length] = 0;`, as C doesn't guarantee this by default.

Answer (score 1):

more simple code using `parseInt()`

```
void loop()
{ 
  if (Serial.available())
  {
   int f = Serial.parseInt();  
   if (f > 0)
   {
     Serial.println(f);
   } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the "readString()" function? Then you can have your code as:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Waiting for intstructions...\n");
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) {
  Serial.println(Serial.readString());
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really coverting it to an integer, perhaps you could expand the answer a bit to include that as well?